# Cast x number of rays in all direction in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to cast x(500) rays in a circular direction(360) in unity. so that 500 rays get cast on equidistance to form a complete circle. I tried something but it leaves out some area I don't know why. how do I make it full circle?

my code

```
    float number_of_rays = 500;
    float angle = 360 / number_of_rays;
    float cast_angle = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rays; i++)
    {
        var dir = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, cast_angle) * transform.right;            
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, dir, Mathf.Infinity);
        if (hit)
        {
            points.Add(hit.point);
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.green,1f);
        }
        cast_angle += angle;
    }
```

[image: Result of the code]

Comment: Oh my lord... OK can I ask WHY?? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to build a mesh(2D plane)  so it's like creating 2d mesh shadows inside a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that maybe it just doesn't find a raycast hit in the space you don't get your rays drawn.

This code seems to work for me.

```
float number_of_rays = 500;
float totalAngle = 360;

float delta = totalAngle / number_of_rays;
Vector3 pos = transform.position;
const float magnitude = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rays; i++)
{
    var dir = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, i * delta) * transform.right;            
    Debug.DrawRay(pos, dir * magnitude, Color.green);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Solved. I am such a fool it was a problem with hit as I was casting rays inside a closed polygon which had edge collider and that was not completely closed as the last and the first points need to be the same of edge collider to make it closed i just missed that part.